# Unity Google Play Games for Android, +200 errors in Xcode

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

In my Unity project I am using the Google Play Games Plugin for Android and it builds in the Android platform without any problem, but when I try to build it using Xcode, it fails and show more than 200 errors that say:

> "Apple Mach-O Linker Error: Undefined symbols for architecture armv7"

I searched in the forum and tried to add some frameworks in Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries, but it does not work. Also, without the GPG Plugin for Android, it builds in Xcode. So, I am wondering if it is not possible to build a project in Xcode that uses Google Play Games Plugin for Android.

Does anyone know something about that? Do I have to separate the Android version (with GPG Android Plugin) and the iOS version (without GPG Android Plugin) into different projects? Or there is a way to build it in Xcode?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Switch your build settings perhaps? Check that you are in the right build mode

Answer (score 1):

Resolved!

It needed this two libraries to work:

GooglePlayGames.bundle
gpg.framework

They are in the [Play Games C++ SDK Version 1.3] that can be downloaded from the google developers page.